# Why do we need CLASS_VERSION in java classes?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm going through some legacy java code. In may classes I found a constant declared with name 'CLASS_VERSION'. I hope they got updated during build. And new build system doesn't even care this variable. I'd like to understand the significance of this variable? If this still valid, how do we use them?

```
public static String CLASS_VERSION = "$Id: filename.java,v 1.17.2.1 2009/01/30 19:38:15 tims Exp $";
```

Appreciate your insights.

Comment: I can't relate this to anything to do with Java. My guess is that it is related to application logic or perhaps a tool that runs across all java files to read this and make some sense.

Comment: your guess may be right. but it may not make much sense with application logic as the value of CLASS_VERSION is keep changing.

Comment: Are you aware that the String value is automatically changed each time the file is checked out or updated?  See [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) in the Subversion manual.  Many other version control systems also have this form of substitution.

Comment: It's automatically updated by the revision control system. This sort of thing can be useful when dealing with problem reports from the field, where you may have many different versions being supported at the same time and you need a quick way to identify exactly which version produced an error.

Comment: Thanks EJP that makes sense. Can the version be identified with the build version? Why do we need to have them in each source file?

Comment: Even if you know the build version, which you may not, you then have to work from that back to the file version, which is what you actually need, and unless your revision control system supports that easily it can be difficult or indeed impossible. The practice isn't seen much in Java, at least I haven't seen it much, but it was standard operating practice in C years ago. You would ask the customer to run 'strings' on the binary, then you would know exactly what you were dealing with in a foolproof way.